# Nuxt.js issue where store state is updating before the url changes

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm currently learning Nuxt.js and hope you can help me.

I have an error when navigating between pages there is a flash for a few milliseconds where my store state updates right before the page url finishes rendering so you see the next page content on the old template briefly and I can't work out why!

Here is the scenario. I'm viewing the /terms/ page and then I navigate to the homepage by clicking the logo. The homepage content renders under the `pages/_slug/index.vue` file for a brief moment until the page url renders.

I noticed it only occurs when the links are `<nuxt-link to="/">` If I use traditional `<a :href="/"></a>` the issue doesn't occur.

I have a global `page` state in the Vuex store which changes from page to page and gets updated via the asyncData method.

Store: `store/index.js`

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import api from '~/api';

const store = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            page: null,
        },

        actions: {
            getHomepage({ commit }) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    api.getHomepage().then(response => {
                        commit('setPage', response);
                        resolve(response);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        reject(error);
                    });
               });
            },

            getPage({ commit }, slug) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    api.getPage(slug).then(response => {
                        commit('setPage', response);
                        resolve(response);
                    })
                   .catch(error => {
                       reject(error);
                   });
                });
            }
        },

        mutations: {
            setPage(state, page) {
                state.page = page;
            }
       }
    })
}

export default store;
```

Homepage template: `pages/index.vue`

```
async asyncData({ store, error, payload }) {
    if(payload) {
        store.commit('setPage', payload.page);
    } else {
        return Promise.all([
            store.dispatch('getHomepage')
        ]).catch(() => {
            error({ message: 'Page not found' });
        });
    }
}
```

Other page template: `pages/_slug/index.vue`

```
async asyncData ({ store, params, error, payload }) {
    if(payload) {
        store.commit('setPage', payload.page);
    } else {
        return Promise.all([
            store.dispatch('getPage', params.slug)
        ]).catch(() => {
            error({ message: 'Page not found' });
        });
    }
}
```

I have a feeling it's because the `page` state is shared across all pages, and when I update the state from page to page it renders the update on the page I'm viewing because it's reactive and watches for changes.

How do I overcome this problem? Is it simply not possible to have 1 state called "page"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are currently simply expecting us to solve the problem **for you**. **PLEASE** give it a try **on your own**, and then show us what you came up with - and if you get stuck **along the way**, feel free to come back and ask for help.

Comment: @Hearen I am not expecting anyone to simply solve the problem. I have tried it on multiple occasions and this is what I currently have, all the code above are snippets from my pages. I'm not sure if it is a nuxt error or something I'm doing wrong, I'm trying to work it out.